# Center text vertically and horizontally, which exceeds its own parent in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have the following solution to center my text:

```css
.close-button {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="close-button">
  <div class="mark">+</div>
</button>
```

As you can see, the element is perfectly centered, I believe. However, when I add a big font-size the element containing text appears at random locations. See below:

```css
.close-button {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  
  /*The line below is new*/
  font-size: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="close-button">
  <div class="mark">+</div>
</button>
```

Why is that and how can I fix that, so that the element is centered again?

Thanks to the answers, I found out that `align-items: center;` solves my issue. However, this does not work in Firefox.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully solve your issue I advise you to read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace) about whitespaces in HTML.
Adding `align-items: center;` will solve the issue, but putting `div` inside `button` is semantically incorrect, source [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element).

**EDIT:**
To avoid issues like I would suggest that you should introduce some `reset.css` for example [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). In your case I believe is wrong `font-family`.
Try adding: `button {font-family: inherit}`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I did not know about these libraries. However, `font-family: inherit;` did not fix it for me. I also included the reset.css file in my project; however, that did not work out. If you are still interested, you can see my edited code at [this](https://replit.com/@martenmatrix/StackOverflowDoNotDelete#style.css) repl.it.

Comment: Everything works as expected. Just font you are using has plus sign not centred in line. Try `font-family:courier`

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
align-items: center;
```

```css
.close-button {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*The line below is new*/
  font-size: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="close-button">
  <div class="mark">+</div>
</button>
```

Comment: This is not centered in Firefox. :(